# Smaller Planet But Similar Time Structure

Tags: planets, time

So I'm not sure this is possible but I was hoping someone might be able to figure out a way for it to work.

My planet is smaller than earth. I'd say about 75% the size. However for plot reasons, I'd like the days to be 24 hours long and the years to be close to the same length as an Earth year.

I haven't exactly defined the size of the planet or its distance from its sun so these things are flexible.

So is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Nothing fancy required at all. Generally speaking, the planet size does not affect its day or year.

Comment: Really? I thought a smaller planet would mean that it would take less time to do one revolution on its axis (thus the day would be shorter).

Comment: For your purposes, the size of the planet will not influence its rate of rotation. If you want this mini earth to have a 24 hour day and a year that is 365 days long, there is no issue whatsoever. For your story make it so.

Comment: 75% of the mass, or 75% the radius/diameter/circumference? (Not that it matters for the question at hand.)

Comment: The day on planet Mars is twenty-five hours. It's a smaller planet, but it's day is close to Earth's. Admittedly it's year is nearly twice as long. That could easily be as same as Earth's. So, yes, a smaller planet with the day and year lengths as Earth's is entirely possible.

Comment: @a4android You can't have a planet in Mars' orbit with Earth's orbital period, assuming that we don't change the star's mass (same central body $\mu = GM$). The *length* of the orbit is related to the orbital radius (actually the semi-major and semi-minor axis) and grows with either, and the mean orbital *velocity* is $\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{r}}$. Farther out means that $r$ is larger, so the orbital velocity is lower; longer orbit and lower velocity means much longer orbital period. Only way to change $\mu$ of a body is to change its mass. (I'm assuming $m_{planet} \ll m_{star}$ here.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling You can't make wrong assumptions about my comment. I was only using Mars as an example in terms of its size. It is obviously ludicrous that a planet in Mars orbit could have an orbital period of one year. Perhaps I could have been clearer. I meant a Mars-sized planet could have an orbit with period of one-year. But not in Mars orbit. OK?

Comment: @a4android - if orbiting a more massive star an orbit at the distance of Mars but twice the speed should be possible, no?  If you can adjust both the mass of star and planet you can find a combination allowing any desired combination of distance between star and planet and year length.

Comment: @Will Yes certainly. I, implicitly, something like this, but expressed it badly, possibly a Mars-sized planet in the equivalent of Earth orbit around a star would also satisfy the necessary criteria. I agree adjusting masses and distances will attain the desired combination of day and year length. My comment didn't really explain how to get there. It just seemed so obvious that was the way to get there. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So is this possible?

Yes, your day/night lengths are due to rotation not size, years are reliant on orbit. Mercury is much smaller than Earth but has an 88 (earth days) year. But its days are 1,408 hours long if you count using Earth hours.

Basically a year is how long the orbit of the sun takes and a day is how fast your planet rotates in relation to the Sun.